# Adding SSL to Apache Server

Tags: apache, ssl, vhosts

We got our SSL certificate today, I'm trying to add the SSL certificate to the domain so that we can access the website through https however I'm running into problems.

We have an apache server running on windows.

The configuration works perfectly for port 80 however when I add port 443 to the config everything stops working.

The error I get when starting apache is

```
The requested operation has failed.
```

I have added the following line

```
Listen 443
```

below the line:

```
Listen 80
```

I have added the following VirtualHost config

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    DocumentRoot "c:/path/to/website"

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "c:/path/to/cert/cert.crt"

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/path/to/cert/key.key"

    SSLCACertificateFile "c:/path/to/cert/bundle.ca-bundle"

</VirtualHost>
```

However whenever I start the apache server after adding this, it doesn't start and I get an error.

I have commented out pieces of code and have narrowed the issue down to the `Listen 443` line. Is there something I am not taking into consideration when adding this?

These are the last 3 lines in the error.log

```
[Thu Jun 08 18:15:31.909142 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 66428:tid 712] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Jun 08 18:15:47.209776 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 67332:tid 620] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Jun 08 18:15:48.067933 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 66428:tid 712] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

**Edit**

This is the response from running `httpd.exe -e debug`

```
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: what is the error you get when starting the apache?

Comment: I believe it’s “operation could not be completed”... I will check in a minute I’ve just packed up to go home so will check when I’m home (wasn’t expecting a quick reply!!)

Comment: No Problem, please update the question with the error message as well

Comment: I've just updated the question

Comment: can you check the apache error logs.

Comment: Where are they?

Comment: It is usually located in directory where apache is installed. Inside the apache folder there should be `logs/error.log`. See the last few lines to get the exact error why apache is not starting

Comment: question updated with the error log from the last hour

Comment: isn't there any `error` labeled in last few lines? Try to start the apache & see if it update the file with error.

Comment: I did just before hand, there’s no error line for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your httpd.conf file looks like, maybe you deleted/changed accidentaly some value.

The very first thing you need to do is to restore your httpd.conf file and start the service without the SSL configuration. Once it works you can proceed with this steps:

In a new file separate all your SSL settings, maybe a new file called **httpd-ssl.conf** is a good name.

After that, at the end of your main **httpd.conf** add this lines to include the new file:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/httpd-ssl.conf
```

This as good practice to avoid changing/deleting accidentally something in the main config and limitate the source of possible errors, you'll know any error will be related to the new file included.

Your new conf/httpd-ssl.conf should look something like this (standard setup):

```
# HTTPS port
Listen 443

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/your_httpd_path/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/your_httpd_path/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/your_httpd_path/logs/access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificates:

SSLCertificateFile "c:/path/to/cert/cert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/path/to/cert/key.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "c:/path/to/cert/bundle.ca-bundle"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "C:/your_httpd_path/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

CustomLog "C:/your_httpd_path/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Have you tried using httpd.exe -e debug? maybe we can find something useful in this mode.

**UPDATE:** Aha! you got an error! It could be a duplicated line somewhere with 443.

Could you check your files in notepad++ and search all the coincidences that match "443"? probably you already had 443 configured and you tried adding it again? You only need to have one line with:

```
Listen 443
```

Or maybe already running in that port? Check with:

```
netstat -na | findstr "443"
```

If you have something like:

```
TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Then something else is running on your 443 port. Anyway, you can change your httpd conf and set any other port like 4443 i.e. or kill the process which is taking 443 now.

Comment: That’s what I was doing. It is working already without the ssl... adding the Listen 443 line makes it fail

Comment: Try my suggestion of creating a new file and including it in the main httpd.conf, don't forget to change the paths of the apache installation, logs and certificates and try again.

Comment: The code provided doesn't work. How do I use httpd.exe?

Comment: Zach you already executed httpd.exe and attached the output. Did you tested the ports as I explained?

Comment: I've solved this now, I had the http service running which was listening on port 443.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne just like I said in my updated answer! nice you've found that out.